# PHP Using curly braces to print variable works different than expected

Tags: php

I want to print a string in PHP that contains html, my code is:

```
<? if (!empty($dias)) {echo 'value="{$dias}"';}?>
```

but it prints value="{$dias}"
What I want to achieve is something similar to

```
<? if (!empty($dias)) {echo 'value="'.$dias.'"';}?>
```

to print value="10". Of course I dont want to concatenate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change quotes:

```
<? if (!empty($dias)) {echo "value='{$dias}'";}?>
// or
<? if (!empty($dias)) {echo "value=\"{$dias}\"";}?>
```

For more details see: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution only happens with strings enclosed in double quotes, so you'd use:

```php
<? if (!empty($dias)) {echo "value=\"{$dias}\"";}?>
```